# Linking to sub-anchors in the "Markdown help" page not working as well as they could

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, permalink, editing-help

On the [Markdown Editing Help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help), every section is lead off by a header element that can be directly linked to (e.g. [*Spoilers*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#spoilers)).  If a section can be expanded (e.g. [*Links*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links)) , each sub-section also has a header element that has an anchor associated with it (e.g. [*Links -> Advanced links*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-links)).

When I click on a link that goes an outer section (e.g. [*Spoilers*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#spoilers) or [*Links*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links)), I'm taken to the help page with the section highlighted (and expanded if it is expandable).  However if I click on a link that goes to a sub-section (e.g. [*Links* -> *Advanced links*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-links)), I'm taken to the help page, only nothing is highlight and nothing is expanded. It's the same UX as if I was just directly linked to the help page, only with the sub-section's anchor tag in the URL.

It would be nice if the sub-section link was at least treated as if the outer section was clicked (e.g. the same view as if I would have clicked on [*Links*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with the next build, the parent section will be used for these sub-sections, so linking to `#advanced-links` will effectively be linking to `#links`.

This was actually *already* the case as far as the JavaScript goes, but some missing attributes on the sub-sections was hindering things here, all better after the next build.